# Listen for changes in Notification Settings for the app

Tags: android, android-notifications

My application is able to trigger some notifications.

[image: notifications_screen]

I would like to be able to detect when the user change a notification setting, for instance when it disables them globally, when he disables one channel, or when he switches the "Allow notification dot"...

I have tried the [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService) approach:

```
public class AppNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

    private static final String TAG = "AppNLS";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind: ");
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind: ");
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationPosted: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerConnected() {
        super.onListenerConnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "onListenerConnected: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerDisconnected() {
        super.onListenerDisconnected();
        Log.d(TAG, "onListenerDisconnected: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationChannelModified(String pkg, UserHandle user, NotificationChannel channel, int modificationType) {
        super.onNotificationChannelModified(pkg, user, channel, modificationType);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationChannelModified: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onListenerHintsChanged(int hints) {
        super.onListenerHintsChanged(hints);
        Log.d(TAG, "onListenerHintsChanged: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn, RankingMap rankingMap) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn, rankingMap);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationPosted: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn, RankingMap rankingMap) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn, rankingMap);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn, RankingMap rankingMap, int reason) {
        super.onNotificationRemoved(sbn, rankingMap, reason);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRemoved: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRankingUpdate(RankingMap rankingMap) {
        super.onNotificationRankingUpdate(rankingMap);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationRankingUpdate: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationChannelGroupModified(String pkg, UserHandle user, NotificationChannelGroup group, int modificationType) {
        super.onNotificationChannelGroupModified(pkg, user, group, modificationType);
        Log.d(TAG, "onNotificationChannelGroupModified: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterruptionFilterChanged(int interruptionFilter) {
        super.onInterruptionFilterChanged(interruptionFilter);
        Log.d(TAG, "onInterruptionFilterChanged: ");
    }

}
```

In the manifest I have added the service:

```
<service android:name=".services.AppNotificationListenerService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And I have granted notification access for my app:
[image: access]

The Service is created an bound properly, I see `onNotificationPosted()` and `onNotificationRemoved()` when a notification is displayed/removed from the Notification area.

However, when I enable/disable the notifications for the app globally, none of the methods get called. And when I enable/disable a channel notification, the only method called is  `onNotificationRankingUpdate()` but this is called when channels of other apps are switched also. I only need from my app.

Is this the right way or what I want to achieve is done in another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As posted in [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228440/1992342), API 28 added system broadcasts for `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED` and `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_GROUP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED` that should suit your needs ([see documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED)).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it only works for Android API. And what about global notifications for the app (this only work for the channels)? Do you know any way to get notified that it has been enabled/disabled?

Comment: Just came across this post, there is an action for the app notification: `ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED` ([see documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#ACTION_APP_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED))

Comment: I created `BroadcastReciver` in Manifest.xml with action intent `<action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_BLOCK_STATE_CHANGED" />`, but `onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent)` is not called